# How to get rid of fireflies ?I had tried many solutions but it doesnt work

Tags: rendering

How to get rid of fireflies ?I had tried many solutions but it doesnt work. I tried to increase the sample count, but it still remain the same. Tried to increase the lighting but it doesnt get rid of the fireflies.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Fireflies are often caused by *too strong* lighting, noise is caused by *too weak* lighting. Check [BlenderGuru's fireflies article](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies) - it goes into more depth.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the layer properties tab and tick the denoising box
[image]

Comment: i tried but it doesnt work

Comment: Are you using a principled bsdf?